# Let T be a tree with t edges and G a graph. Prove that if |E(G)| ≥ t · |V (G)|, then T is a subgraph of G.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I tried to prove it by induction on t. Obviously true when t=1 and 2. Suppose true when t=k, then when tree *T* has t=k+1, we could remove a leaf *x* from *T* and thus go back to case t=k, but I have no idea how to extend that to a tree isomorphic to *T*.

There are similar questions which restrict on degree of vertices of *G*, I also tried to use $$\sum_{v\in G}{d(v)}=2|E(G)|$$ but did not find a way. (e.g. [Trees that are isomorphic to a subgraph of a graph G.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321039/trees-that-are-isomorphic-to-a-subgraph-of-a-graph-g))

Comment: Stop cheating. Come see me in my office right now : MA C1 557.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We prove by induction on $t$. (Assume G is not a null graph)

We can easily verify that when t=1,2 the statement is true. 
Let $T$ be a tree with t $edges$, then it is easy to see that $\max\limits_{v \in T} deg(v) = t$

Suppose true when t-1, then when t:
We have $$|E(G)| \geq t |V(G)|$$
Let *U* be the set of vertices of with degree not greater than $t-1$ in *G*

We have $$|E(G)|\leq|E(G\setminus U)|+(t-1)|U|$$
$$|V(G)|=|V(G\setminus U)|+|U|$$ 
Combining them, we get $$|E(G\backslash U)| \geq t |V(G\backslash U)|+|U| \geq(t-1)|V(G\backslash U)|$$
Which means we can embed $T'$ in $G\backslash U$ (where $T' :=T-x$, $x$ is a leaf of $T$),   now we can add back that leaf in $G$ since all vertices in $G\backslash U$ has degree larger than t (considering its degree in $G$), but in $T'$ maximum degree is $t-1$.

Comment: I really ain't sure about that...Does that still work if $U$ is empty?  Because nothing guarantees that $G$ has degree $1$ vertices.  Also, how does $G \setminus U$ having only degree $2+$ vertices guarantee tht the leaves can be inserted back?

Comment: @ManuelLafond it works when U is empty, but you are right, G∖U having only degree 2+ vertices cannot guarantee that... I think this proof is wrong.

Comment: @ManuelLafond I modified the answer, please see if it's correct now. thanks a lot for your comment !!

Answer (score 1):

Assume the statement for some $k\geqslant1$. Let $G$ be a graph with $|E|\geqslant (k+1)|V|$ and $T$ a tree with $k+1$ edges. The degree of any vertex in $G$ is at most $|V|-1$, so if $G'$ is a subgraph of $G$ obtained by removing a vertex, 
$$|E'|\geqslant (k+1)|V|-(|V|-1)=k|V|+1\geqslant k(|V|-1). $$
Therefore if $T'$ is a subgraph of $T$ obtained by removing an edge, there is a subgraph $S'$ of $G'$ with $S'\cong T'$. Since the vertex removed from $G$ was arbitrary, it follows that there is a subgraph of $G$ congruent to $T$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I am a little confused about the last sentence. Why the arbitrary choice of the vertex removed leads to the existence of a subgraph of G congruent to T?

Comment: Indeed, I am missing some things as well.  Here $T'$ is not a tree - it has two connected components.  So $S'$ could be two graphs very far apart in $G'$.  How can you guarantee that the edge removed from $T$ can be gained back in $G$ ?

Comment: @ManuelLafond I think we could remove a leaf from *T* to guarantee *T'* being a tree. If *T'* is not a tree we cannot use induction hypothesis.

Comment: @ManuelLafond  And how to guarantee that the edge removed can be gained back?..

Comment: Now I seems to have a full answer, thanks a lot for your help!!